# Break out a for loop C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

Im trying to break out of a for loop, inside a nested if statement.. So basically im doing MasterMind Game, and im trying to know how much the user actually go correct(discaring positions).. So basically i came up with storing the AI's binary number in a array, then comparing each user binary digit against it.. As soon as a binary digit from user is equal to one binary digit from AI, then it should break out of for loop... I thought about it this way and i did:

```
void MasterMind::evaluateCorrection()
{
    // AI : 1  1  1  0
    //USER: 1  0  1  1
    //Store AI In Array
    int AI[3];
    int count = 0;

   std::copy(binaries.begin(), binaries.end(), AI);
   for(std::vector<char>::iterator itAI= numbers.begin() ; itAI != numbers.end(); itAI++)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<=3;i++)
        {
            char numberAt = *itAI;
            int intNumberAt = numberAt - '0'; 
            if(intNumberAt = AI[i])
            {
                cout << intNumberAt << " VS " << AI[i] << endl;
                actuallyCorrect++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "\n ACTUALLY CORRECT " << actuallyCorrect << endl;
}
```

So when i get this code in bash:

```
 BINARY : 
1111


 PLEASE ENTER A 4 DIGIT BINARY! OR PROGRAM WILL EXIT 

        1123
YOU HAVE 2 POSITIONS CORRECT 
1 VS 1
1 VS 1
1 VS 1
1 VS 1

 ACTUALLY CORRECT 4
```

That is obviously not correct.. I entered 1123 and it just said 4 are actually correct... Well actually there is only 2 that are actually right the 1 and 1. Please Help!

Comment: `AI[3]` is out-of-range, so you must not access `AI[i]` when `i=3`.

Comment: `intNumberAt = AI[i]` is an assignment, not comparision. Are you sure this is what you want to do?

Comment: Wow there @MikeCAT Woww... i done goof

Comment: Ok that worked @MikeCAT thanks for the help, i would be happy to accept your anwser..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `AI[3]` is out-of-range, so you must not access `AI[i]` when `i=3` and the size of the array should be increased.
- `intNumberAt = AI[i]` is an assignment. Use `==` operator to do equality check.

Try this:

```
void MasterMind::evaluateCorrection()
{
    // AI : 1  1  1  0
    //USER: 1  0  1  1
    //Store AI In Array
    int AI[4] = {0}; // initialize for in case what is copied has insufficient number of elements
    int count = 0;

   std::copy(binaries.begin(), binaries.end(), AI);
   for(std::vector<char>::iterator itAI= numbers.begin() ; itAI != numbers.end(); itAI++)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<=3;i++)
        {
            char numberAt = *itAI;
            int intNumberAt = numberAt - '0';
            if(intNumberAt == AI[i])
            {
                cout << intNumberAt << " VS " << AI[i] << endl;
                actuallyCorrect++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "\n ACTUALLY CORRECT " << actuallyCorrect << endl;
}
```

Comment: perhaps the op wanted AI[4]. Nice observation about `if(intNumberAt = AI[i])`.I recently read about a priority 1 bug that plagued Sunsoft back in 1993. After some intensive debuggin sessions, they traced it to a statement that read `x==2`. The programmer's finger had bounced on the equal key, accidentally pressing it twice instead of once.. Here the op might have have an `equals` key reluctant to admit key press. ;)